# Multiple (3) factors for sumifs (possibly) needed in Excel

Tags: excel, criteria, sumifs

I am using the below formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(AG7:AG2619=T3,A7:A2619),IF(AG7:AG2619=T3,A7:A2619)),1))
```

But I need to add a third criteria, I only want to it to count if the text "STP" occurs correspondingly in the column "AI", or more specifically, AI7:AI2619.

New here, so if more details needed I am happy to provide. Grateful for any assistance.

I'm not that experience at Excel. All tutorials I can find refer to 'multiple criteria', then demonstrate a maximum of 2.

I've tried effectively replicating the above once more, but to no avail.

I've also tried the monkey with a typewriter approach, but it's driving me bananas.

Comment: You would multiply the various Booleans: `AG7:AG2619=T3` would become `(AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AI7:AI2619="STP")` in both `IF(...)`

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for this, but I can't get it to work, are you able to provide the formula you'd use? Understood if this is a bit too much. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail: =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(AG7:AG2619=T3,A7:A2619)*(AG7:AG2619=T3,A7:A2619)*(ai7:ai2619="Yes",ai7:ai2619),1)))

Comment: that is not what I told you to do.  I said `AG7:AG2619=T3 would become (AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AI7:AI2619="STP")` not what you have:  `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AI7:AI2619="STP"),A7:A2619),IF((AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AI7:AI2619="STP"),A7:A2619)),1))`

Comment: Ah, I see. However, Excel doesn't like it: =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AI7:AI2619="STP"),(AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AI7:AI2619="STP"))),1))

Comment: Again you are changing the formula.  Use the one put in: `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AI7:AI2619="STP"),A7:A2619),IF((AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AI7:AI2619="STP"),A7:A2619)),1))`

Comment: May I ask why you are not using SUMIFS?: `=SUMIFS(A7:A2619,AG7:AG2619,T3,AI7:AI2619,"STP")`?

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! I have one last question for the evening; I have another field whereby instead of looking for “STP”, I need the same data to look for a value of less than 2 in Column AL, specifically AL7:AL2619. I tried extrapolating your formula as per the below but no joy:
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AL7:AL2619=(<)),A7:A2619),IF((AG7:AG2619=T3)*(AL7:AL2619=(<)),A7:A2619)),1))

Comment: `AL7:AL2619=(<)` should be `AL7:AL2619<2`

Comment: Thanks Scott, this has been very helpful.